# java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is Denied) in a static method to move file

Tags: java, io

I was met with a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\520\Desktop\Thing (Access is denied)` error when running the following script to move files. Does this mean I should run my IDE under admin privileges?

```
public static void moveFiles(){
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        try{
            File afile = new File("C:\\Users\\520\\Desktop\\hey.txt"); // Gotta specify initial path. Consider adding an input for this
            File bfile = new File("C:\\Users\\520\\Desktop\\Thing");

            inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length; // copy the file content in bytes
            while((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            afile.delete();
            System.out.println("File was copied successfully!");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Before you try doing it as an admin, make sure that Windows has read privileges granted to that file and its folder.

Comment: It appears I have solved the issue. I simply made a new `.txt` file in `/Thing/`, however, it also appears I made wrong sense of what this script actually does. I want to move a file to a folder, not really replace a file. Is there any workarounds to this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to adjust the destination file object so that if it is a directory, it will instead use the source file's name within that directory.

```
if (bfile.isDirectory()) bfile = new File(bfile, afile.getName());
```